# Bind click event to dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have this template (Mustage):

```
<script id="serviceTemplate" type="text/template">
    {{#data}}
        <li class="service-listitem">
            <div class="service-item">
                <h6><b>{{Type}}:</b> {{Name}}</h6>
                <div>
                    {{Remarks}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tb">
                <a href="#" class="tbdiv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>Info</a>
                <a href="#" class="tbdiv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    {{/data}}
</script>
```

And I'm binding the `click` event like so:

```
$(".tbdiv").on("click", { id: 'test' }, addTo);

function addTo(event) {
   debugger;
   alert("id: " + event.data.id);
}
```

But the `click` event never gets fired. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the event problem:

```
$(document).on("click", ".tbdiv", { id: 'test' }, addTo);

function addTo(event) {
   debugger;
   alert("id: " + event.data.id);
}
```

Comment: Crazy, I got my code for the `on()` from the net. Is it always `$(document).on()`? +1 and marked.

Comment: When you use $("element").on() listens events from that element, but $(document).on("click","event",callback) fires every click event listened from document and fires the callback if the clicked element matches with the given argument, event delegation